# Calculating the Variance using Delta Method

Tags: delta-method

I'm trying to find the variance of $L$, $Var(L)$, using the delta method (I want to find a closed form). $L$ is defined as:
$$L = \frac{A}{B}  + \frac{C}{D}$$
All $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are dependent.

But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: The answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21875/delta-method-and-correlated-variables/21888#21888 will get you started; your problem has four variables and will therefore be more complicated, but the core approach is the same.

Comment: Note, too, that the delta method is an *approximation,* so please don't overinterpret any "closed form" result!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For notational simplicity define $X_1=A$, $X_2=B$, $X_3=C$, $X_4=D$ and  $L=f(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ with $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) = \frac{x_1}{x_2}+\frac{x_3}{x_4}$. A first order expansion  around $\mu = (\mu_1, \mu_2,\mu_3, \mu_4)$ where $\mu_i=\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ shows that the following approximation holds
$$L \approx f(\mu) + \sum_{i=1}^4 \partial_i f(\mu) \, (X_i-\mu_i)$$
as soon as the quantities $X_i-\mu_i$ are small enough.
Since $\mathbb{E}\big[\sum_{i=1}^4 \partial_i f(\mu) \, (X_i-\mu_i) \big]=0$ it thus follows that the variance of $L$ can also be approximated by 
$$\textrm{var}(L) \approx \mathbb{E} \Big[ \Big\{\sum_{i=1}^4 \partial_i f(\mu) \, (X_i-\mu_i) \Big\}^2 \Big] \\ 
= \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq 4} \textrm{Cov}(X_i,X_j) \partial_i f(\mu) \partial_j f(\mu).$$