# How to compute sample variance and/or mean square error as a percentage?

Tags: regression, variance, error, percentage

Say I have a set of measurement values $y_\text{m} = (y_{\text{m},1}, \dots y_{\text{m},N}) $, and compare these with some ground truth $y = (y_1, \dots y_N)$. Then, if I understood correctly, I can estimate the (sample) variance of the error $(y_\text{m} - y)$ in my measurement values as

\begin{equation}
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (y_{\text{m},i} - y_i)^2}{N-1}
\end{equation}

(and, if I'm working with a fit instead of ground truth, this changes to the mean square error, with $N-2$ in the denominator).

According to the explanation [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/book/export/html/810), with a sufficiently well-behaved error, I could even compute a confidence interval for $\sigma^2$.

Now, if I'm interested in the relative error, expressed as a percentage, $100 \times (y_\text{m} - y)/y$, how do these estimates for $\sigma^2$ and MSE change? And can I still compute a confidence interval in that case?

EDIT: Sorry, I just realised that in the ground truth case the variance doesn't change, because ground truth is not a stochastic variable. So my question only pertains to the MSE case.

EDIT 2: Doing a further search based on @Demetri Pananos's comments, it looks like the answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30309), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19580), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21888) may help me get started

Comment: You could use the delta method, but you would need to estimate the covariance between the model predictions and the data.

Comment: Thanks @DemetriPananos, where do I find more information about the delta method?

Comment: you could start with Wikipedia. Most graduate level books on stats should also cover the topic.

Comment: @DemetriPananos, got it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method. It's not quite what I was looking for I think, but your hint is clear enough, I'll go and look elsewhere for an answer to my question. Thanks for your help.